# Why do inline Javascript calls get automatically removed by WP Bakery Page Builder?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, visual-composer

When adding a Javscript call to an element via WP Bakery Page Builder, e.g. via

```
<a href="javascript:someFunc();">Click</a>
```

or

```
<span onclick="someFunc();">Click</span>
```

the code gets automatically removed after saving & closing the respective element.

Can someone explain to me why that is and how to circumvent it /an alternative solution looks like?

Comment: Probably for security reasons, although you should ask them directly to be sure.

Comment: Probably because the Page Builder creates pre-defined blocks of HTML and CSS.  The only attributes (arguments) they take are whatever is expressly allowed through the UI.